# How to set Headers in TRON api call?

Tags: ios, swift

I am newbie to the programming in iOS. I am building just simple app where I need to hit APIs for which I am using TRON.

My code Look like this

```
let tron = TRON(baseURL: "http://localhost:3000")
let request: APIRequest<HomeDataSource, JSONError> = tron.request("/api/v2/users/cards")
```

Its working perfectly fine but I want to set headers in above API call. can someone tell me how to set headers? I found the syntax in the documentation but couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple. Just do

```
request.headers = ["key": "value"]
```

From [Documentation](https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON)

Comment: yes Sir, I found out solution for this from Documentation